# Django adding a feedback form on every page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form view for user feedback:

**urls.py:**

```
url(
    r'^feedback/$',
    'tool.views.Feedback',
    name='feedback'
),
url(
    r'^thanks/$',
    direct_to_template, {
        'template': 'tool_feedback_thanks.html'
    },
    name='feedback_thanks'
),
```

**forms.py:**

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.Form):
    yes_no = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=YES_NO_CHOICE,
        initial=1,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'can_reveal_input'}),
        label="Are you happy with Our service?"
    )
    comments = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
            'class': 'hidden', 'placeholder': 'Leave us your comments...'
        }),
        required=False,
        label=""
    )
```

**views.py:**

```
def Feedback(request,
                 template_name='tool_feedback.html'):
    title = u'Leave us some feedback'
    form = FeedbackForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        yes_no = form.cleaned_data['yes_no']
        comments = form.cleaned_data['comments']
        sender = "A Unirac website user"
        recipients = ['person@example.com']
        send_mail(yes_no, comments, sender, recipients)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('feedback_thanks')
        )
    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'title': title,
        'form': form,
    }, RequestContext(request))
```

This works a treat, but now the client is asking that this form be included on every single page. I guess the form can be submitted via JS to the appropriate URL, but what is the best way to include the unbound form on every page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd create a context processor, to include the form in every view.

**EDIT:**

To get the user to the previous URL he/she was browsing, you can use just URLs.

```
# yourapp/context_processors.py
def feedback_form_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'feedback_form': FeedbackForm(),
        'feedback_form_url': reverse("feed_app:form_process", args=(request.path))
    }
```

This is how urls.py could look like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('feed_app.views',
    url(r'^process-feedback-form/(?P<next_url>\d+)', 'form_process', name='form_process'),
)
```

And the view for the form:

```
def form_process(request, next_url):
    # Process form, do your stuff here
    # if its valid redirect to the url
    return redirect(next_url)
```

And you should structure your templates to have the correct layout. For example, having a base template:

```
# templates/base.html
<html>
<body>
..
{% block maincontent %}
{% endblock %}
..
{# The form!!! #}
<form action='{{feedback_form_url}}' method='POST'>
@csrftoken
{{ feedback_form.as_p }}
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

To create a simple view just use the correct template.

```
# templates/just_a_random_view.html

{% extends base.html %}

{% block maincontent %}
<h1>Content!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, include it in your settings:

```
# settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    ...
    "yourapp.context_processors.feedback_form_context_processor"
)
```

Comment: This looks great. So, the 'just_a_random_template.html' should be the template I was using for the distinct form (i.e. tool_feedback.html)?

Comment: No, that's just an example for view you need to write. That `just_a_random_template.html` could be `login.html` or `process_purchase.html`. The idea is that all the templates you use in your views extend from base.html that has the form.

Comment: So, I included the form from the context processor in my `base.html` and directed the form to the existing view, grabbing the page url as a GET variable. That way I can validate and return to the same page. This works, but does it seem like a reasonable pattern?

Comment: I made some changes to help you. You have all the logic in my answer. You shouldn't have problems to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer!

Comment: In Theory this sounds so complicated, but with your instruction it was a cake walk. :D Thank You so much.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that easiest way to include form would be to use a [assignment_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags):

In template library:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def feedback_form(format_string):
    return FeedbackForm()
```

In template

```
{% feedback_form as form %}
{# display form... %}
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Comment: Ok - this looks interesting - could you elaborate a little for my use case? Should I use the decorator on my view? Can I include this in the `base.html` template?

Comment: You do not need decorator, and you can use this in your ``base.html`` template. Just include your template library in base.html. It is easiest if you  handle form processing with ajax or on other URL.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @bmihelac, who's answer worked really well for me. Since django 2.0 `assignment_tag` is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.9/#assignment-tag) in favor of `simple_tag`. So you can pretty much follow his answer exactly by replacing `assignment_tag` with `simple_tag`, like so:

```
from django import template

from .forms import FeedbackForm

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def feedback_form():
    return FeedbackForm()
```

And then just refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout for info about how to import it into the template!